# Can't include \url within \hl from soul package

Tags: urls, soul

I am wanting to include a link within some highlighted text. The highlighting is currently being performed by the [soul](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul?lang=en) package but the following example shows it returns a bunch of warnings and fails to render the link:

```
\documentclass{book}

% Package used for highlighting
\usepackage{soul}

% Link setup
\usepackage[ps2pdf]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[anythingbreaks]{breakurl}

\begin{document}

Link works here: \url{http://google.co.uk/}

Link within highlight fails: \hl{ Highlight \url{http://google.co.uk/} link }

\end{document}
```

> Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. l.14    Complains when link is within
>   highlight: \hl
>                                                     { Highlight link \url{http...

Any idea how I can get links to appear within the `\hl` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems wrapping the robust `\hbox` command round the `\url` command prevents the fragility of the `url` command from interfering with the `hl` command. This does mean the URL cannot break between lines but this will have to do for now, unless anyone can find a better solution.

```
\documentclass{book}

% Package used for highlighting
\usepackage{soul}

% Link setup
\usepackage[ps2pdf]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[anythingbreaks]{breakurl}

\begin{document}

Link: \url{http://google.co.uk/}

Link within highlight: \hl{Highlight \hbox{\url{http://google.co.uk/}} link}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `\url` command is fragile.  The following works.

```
\documentclass{book}

% Package used for highlighting
\usepackage{soul}

% Link setup
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[anythingbreaks]{breakurl}

\begin{document}

Link works here: \url{http://google.co.uk/}

Complains when link is within highlight: \hl{ Highlight link \protect\url{http://google.co.uk/} }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but when I add text after the link the highlighting disappears. `\hl{ Highlight link \protect\url{http://google.co.uk/} after }`

Comment: You're right; I'm out of my depth.

Comment: That makes both of us! I have updated my question to include text after the link to be more indicative of the environment the solution will be used within.