# soul package command \hl can not work with escaped space

Tags: soul

It seems that `\hl` command in the soul package can not work with escaped space. A minimal non-working example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\begin{document}

\hl{can\ we\ highlight}

\end{document}
```

The error message is

> Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

Some posts (for example, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160220/french-accents-in-hl-from-soul-package) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321549/cant-include-url-within-hl-from-soul-package)) suggest using `\mbox`(or `\hbox`) to wrap the text or using `\protect`. While these methods work, they have some drawbacks:

- If `\mbox` is used, long text will not wrap normally.
- If `\protect` is used, the background color for text will disappear.

How to solve this problem more elegantly?

**Edit**

The solution shared by Skillmon works for English, but not for Chinese. The following MWE will illustrate that.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\hlORIG\hl

\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
\RenewDocumentCommand \hl { +m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_jdhao_hlx_tl { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_jdhao_hlx_tl { \  } { ~ }
    \exp_args:NV \hlORIG \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\hl{test\ test}  %% pass!
\hl{测试\ 测试} %% fail!

\end{document}
```

It is interesting that English test passed, but the Chinese test failed. The error message is the same.

Comment: Out of interest: Why do you want to escape spaces after normal words?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to convert Markdown to PDF using Pandoc. For space in inline code, Pandoc will escape it, which unfortunately conflicts with soul.

Answer (score 6):

With a helper macro which converts all the explicit spaces (`\`) into a normal space, this is possible (I redefined the `\hl` macro so that you don't have to change anything else):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\hlORIG\hl

\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
\RenewDocumentCommand \hl { +m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_jdhao_hlx_tl { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_jdhao_hlx_tl { \  } { ~ }
    \exp_args:NV \hlORIG \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hl{can\ we\ highlight}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Working with Chinese input, but breaking automatic hyphenation (you can still provide manual hyphenation with `\-`):

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage[chinese,main=english]{babel}
\let\hlORIG\hl

\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
\RenewDocumentCommand \hl { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_jdhao_hlx_tl { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_jdhao_hlx_tl { \  } { ~ }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { [^\s\c{-}] } { \c{hbox} \0 } \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
    \exp_args:NV \hlORIG \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% for comparison of hyphenating 
\rule{.9\textwidth}{1pt}possibility\ to\ highlight

\rule{.9\textwidth}{1pt}\hl{possibility\ to\ highlight}

\rule{.9\textwidth}{1pt}\hl{pos\-sibility\ to\ highlight}

\rule{.9\textwidth}{1pt}\hlORIG{possibility to highlight}

\hl{汤面}
\hl{汤面}
\hl{测试\ 测试}
%\hlORIG{汤面}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT2:**

Yet another version which allows you to use braces and other stuff in the argument of `\hl`. Note that both this version and the second version break maths in the argument of `\hl`. You can change the regular expression used as the first argument of `\regex_replace_all:nnN` to fix more issues you're facing, I'm not willing to put more time into fiddling with it.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage[chinese,main=english]{babel}
\let\hlORIG\hl

\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
\RenewDocumentCommand \hl { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_jdhao_hlx_tl { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_jdhao_hlx_tl { \  } { ~ }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c[^CBEMTPUDA]\S } { \c{hbox} \0 } \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
    \exp_args:NV \hlORIG \l_jdhao_hlx_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% for comparison of hyphenating 
\rule{.9\textwidth}{1pt}possibility\ to\ highlight

\rule{.9\textwidth}{1pt}\hl{possibility\ to\ highlight}

\rule{.9\textwidth}{1pt}\hl{pos\-sibility\ \textbackslash{} to\ highlight}

\rule{.9\textwidth}{1pt}\hlORIG{possibility\textbackslash{} to highlight}

\hl{汤面}
\hl{汤面}
\hl{测试\ 测试}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that this solution does not work for Chinese text, it only works for English. I have tried to test it with Chinese text and failed.

Comment: @jdhao can you please update your question then, to include Chinese as well? This way any future answerer knows that this has to work for Chinese. And please also add information which engine you use to compile (there might be a clever solution for LuaTeX if you use it).

Comment: @jdhao I can add code which works with chinese text, but breaks hyphenation (line breaking still works, though).

Comment: I have updated the question to include the fail case for Chinese.

Comment: @jdhao my updated answer does work with your updated MWE (though breaking hyphenation -- but I don't know how hyphenation works in Chinese anyway).

Comment: You can use the test case I used, i.e., `\hl{测试\ 测试}`. On my machine, error will occur.

Comment: @jdhao I did and it works (with the second code block of my answer) on my machine. Did you try the correct code block? Sadly atm hyphenation isn't working with that approach. I'll look into that later this day.

Comment: Thanks, the second code works. I have been using the first code block.

Comment: @jdhao hyphenation *could* be possible but needs at least 2 runs with parsing the log file for the output of `\showhyphen` with some additional stuff around it (as markers). That's nothing I want to do right now. I hope the above is enough. I've made manual hyphenation with `\-` possible.

Comment: @jdhao does this answer satisfy your needs? If so, could you please accept it? If not, could you please say what's still needed?

Comment: It seems that `\textbackslash{}`  can not work with the new `\hl` command.

Comment: @jdhao see my edit for a version which solve that. Note however, that you don't have to use `\textbackslash{} ` but could also use `\textbackslash\ ` to force a space after `\textbackslash`.